# not able to push an object into an array which is in nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is giving an error that push is not a function

```
req.User.messages.push(result)
```

this is not showing any error, but giving null in res.json()

```
[req.User.messages].push(result);
 return res.json(req.User.messages);
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.User)`?

Comment: If `.push` is not a function, then `req.User.messages` is not an Array.

Comment: Don't pollute the `req` by using it for temporary storage of your messages.  Instead define a new empty array to store the messages and return that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether req.User.messages exists and that it is an Array

```
 if (req.User.messages && Array.isArray(req.User.messages)) {
  req.User.messages.push(result)
} else {
  req.User.messages = [result];
}
```

This ensures that you only append to an Array

Comment: sorry, you are correct, req.User gives only id, there is no messages

Answer (score 1):

`[req.User.messages].push(result);`

This code doesn't make any changes to `req.User.messages`. Instead it creates another 1 element array and push the result to that array.

> this is not showing any error, but giving null in res.json()

This means that the req.User.messages is already null.

So you need to first validate if req.User.messages is a valid array.

Comment: yes, you are right, there is no messages in req.User. I have to find  the model using req.User._id